# disaggregation of point rainfall data using r programming

Tags: r

i have the following annual daily maximum rainfall data which i need to disaggregate into hourly rainfall data using r programming package. i am aware that certain packages are capable to simulating with minimal error e.g BLRPM, tempdisagg, etc. however i am new in the programming language and i need the algorithm or r code to perform it in r language using any of the packages listed.

pls kindly assist see the data below:

```
YEAR    MAX DAILY
1955    79.76
1956    64.77
1957    67.82
1958    44.2
1959    52.83
1960    60.45
1961    77.72
1962    50.04
1963    59.94
1964    90.68
1965    101.09
1966    55.88
1967    97.79
1968    76.96
1969    77.98
1970    48.77
1971    68
1972    69.769
1973    69.769
1974    69.769
1975    52.1
1976    69.769
1977    74.3
1978    65.1
1979    79.2
1980    77.9
1981    55.1
1982    58.3
1983    86.6
1984    53.2
1985    60.6
1986    57.6
1987    108.1
1988    132.1
1989    45.9
1990    55.8
1991    118.6
1992    59.6
1993    86
1994    52
1995    78.5
1996    58
1997    48.3
1998    60.4
1999    72.5
2000    83.9
2001    58.3
2002    57.9
2003    68.7
2004    70.1
```

Comment: Sorry, you have one value per year and you want to translate it to hourly? How would that be possible?

Comment: hi i. spring, these data was extracted from a monthly series, so would a monthly time series work?